# How do I load variables from two files in ansible, given one filename will have variable in itself?

Tags: variables, ansible

I am stuck in a situation where I have variable files for each host and I want to load variables from two files in an ansible task, one global and one host specific. Here is the scenario:

This is the directory Structure.

```
.
|__configfile
|__inventory
|__playbook.yaml
|__vars
   |__global.yaml
   |__host_10.84.0.146.yaml
   |__host_10.84.0.206.yaml
   |__host_10.84.0.251.yaml
```

1. `configfile` - This is the file to configure on remote. This is a part of RPM Installation.

```yaml
param1: {{ value_global }}
param2: {{ value_hostSpecific }}
```

2. `inventory`

```ini
[instance_IP]
10.84.0.251
10.84.0.206
10.84.0.146
```

3. `playbook.yaml`

```yaml
- hosts: instance_IP
  tasks:
    - name: copy config files list
      copy:
        src: "./configfile"
        dest: "/tmp"
    - fetch:
        src: "/tmp/configfile"
        dest: "templates/configfile"
        flat: yes
    - name: Load Variable
      ansible.builtin.include_vars:
        files:
          - './vars/global.yaml'
          - './vars/host_{{ inventory_hostname }}.yaml'
    - name: Using template to patch files
      template:
        src: "templates/configfile"
        dest: "/tmp/configfile"
```

4. Variable files - 1 Global and 3 Host specific.
   a. `global.yaml`

```
value_global: Value_global
```

b. `host_10.84.0.146.yaml`

```
value_hostSpecific: Value_10.84.0.146
```

c. `host_10.84.0.206.yaml`

```
value_hostSpecific: Value_10.84.0.206
```

d. `host_10.84.0.251.yaml`

```
value_hostSpecific: Value_10.84.0.251
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want user to populate the variable values midway during execution by pausing the playbook. Therefore cannot load it before the playbook execution.

You are misinterpreting how Ansible resolves variable values through jinja2 templating. Variable content is evaluated every time it is **used**, not when it is *declared*. Therefore, you can definitely define a variable at start which is dependent on an other variable you will create/populate later at runtime. You just have to be cautious setting defaults and/or not using that var before it can actually be interpreted correctly.

That being said, you are trying to reinvent the wheel as everything is available in Ansible out-of-the-box to address your issue. You are also making things overly complicated and I don't understand your back-and-fourth copying the template file to fetch it back and pushing it as a templated file again...

As an entry-point to the subject and to understand how the below example is working, you can read [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html) and more specifically the chapter [Organizing host and group variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables).

Here is an example from what I understood you want to achieve using a correctly crafted project directory.

File structure:

```
.
├── inventories
│   └── default
│       ├── group_vars
│       │   └── all.yml
│       ├── hosts.yml
│       └── host_vars
│           ├── 10.84.0.146.yaml
│           └── 10.84.0.206.yaml
├── playbook.yml
└── templates
    └── configfile.j2
```

`hosts.yml` inventory:

```yaml
---
instance_IP:
  10.84.0.206:
  10.84.0.146:
```

`all.yml` group vars:

```yaml
---
value_global: Value_global
```

`10.84.0.146.yaml` host variables:

```yaml
---
value_hostSpecific: Value_10.84.0.146
```

`10.84.0.206.yaml` host variables:

```yaml
---
value_hostSpecific: Value_10.84.0.206
```

`configfile.j2` template:

```
param1: {{ value_global }}
param2: {{ value_hostSpecific }}
```

Given the above inventory, the following `playbook.yml` will push the expected template to the remote targets replacing the variables with the relevant values:

```yaml
---
- name: Configure remote target
  hosts: instance_IP
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Push template config to remote target
      ansible.builtin.template:
        src: configfile.j2
        dest: /some/path/on/remote/host/configfile
```

Comment: The reason I am copying template/config file back-and-forth is because they will be installed as a part of rpm installation with {{ placeholders }} in it. For patching them I have to fetch it and then copy it back. I don't know how to patch them directly on remote.

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. A much better scenario is to deploy a default configuration file with your package and either 1) modify it from ansible with lineinfile/blockinfile 2) rewrite it completely with a template you hold on Ansible side. Letting users possibly mess with a template on target side that will most probably make your deploy fail one day is not a good option.

Comment: It is working as expected. I searched the internet and did not find anything on the naming convention of the variable file. If I rename the global file to anything else but all.yml, it does not work. And with all.yml everything works. Is this ansible standard? 
Also, I accept your suggestion.

Comment: Edited the question with links to answer your latest concern. As an example for this specific case, renaming `all.yml` (i.e. the variables for the special group `all`) to `instance_IP.yml` would still work as all your example machines are in that group.